# Prove that incentre and excenter of a triangle are harmonic conjugates.

Tags: triangles, coordinate-systems

[image: "Diagram (click here)"]

Given the coordinates of a triangle $A(x_1,y_1)$, $B(x_2,y_2)$, $C(x_3,y_3)$, prove that the *incentre* and *excenter* of the triangle $\triangle ABC$ are harmonic conjugates with respect to the $A$ and $D$ lying on internal angle bisector passing through the the incentre and excenter.

In the image embedded for example, prove $AI/ID=AI_A/AD$.

I could only think of $AI/ID=(b+c)/a$. I couldn't prove the RHS equal to it. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I assume the problem means "with respect to $A$ and $D$." In other words, you would like to prove that $AI/ID=AI_A/I_AD$. You can do this by proving that both are equal to $AB/BC$. That $AI/ID=AB/BD$ is the [bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) applied to the triangle $\triangle ABD$ and the bisector $BI$. The other proportion $AI_A/I_AD=AB/BD$ can be proven the same way the bisector theorem is proven. For example, using law of sines on the triangles $\triangle ABI_A$ and on the triangle $\triangle BDI_A$.

Comment: Take into account that angles $\angle ABI_A$ and $\angle DBI_A$ add up to $\pi$ and therefore have the same sine.

Comment: @NDB could you please provide more details. On which triangle and how am I supposed to apply the sine law. Thanks.

Comment: @NDB Thanks for you help! I finally could prove the formula for coordinates of excenter using simple geometry (nowhere found!)